# Variáveis de sessão $_SESSION vs variaveis de classe em PHP

Tags: php, classes, instanciar-objeto

Queria saber os prós e/ou os contras de se usar variáveis de sessão no 
construtor de classes ou até mesmo dentro dos métodos de uma classe.

Digamos que eu tenha a seguinte classe:

```
class minhaClasse {
    private $arrEnvSettings;

    public function __construct(array $setParam=NULL) {

        $arrIni["userType"] = $_SESSION["userType"];
        //$arrIni["outrasVar"] = "valor padrão de inicialização";


        //Unindo $setParam com $arrIni
        //Permite mudar os valores de inicialização
        if(!is_null($setParam)){
            $this->$arrEnvSettings =  array_merge($arrIni,$setParam);
        }
        else{
            $this->$arrEnvSettings =$arrIni;
        }
    }

    public function homePage() {

        if($this->$arrEnvSettings["userType"]=1){
            //Mostrar home page admin
        }
        else{
            //Mostrar home page para não admin
        }

    }
}
```

Como exemplo tenho um sistema que foi concebido para ser acessado digamos por 8 tipos de usuários.
Logo no início do processo, quando estivermos testando o login e password poderemos recuperar o `$userType` e gravarmos dentro da sessão `$_SESSION["userType"]=1` por exemplo (ADMIN).

Posteriormente quando eu for instanciar o objeto, poderia usar os dois exemplos seguintes:

```
//Exemplo - 1
$objSite = new minhaClasse();
echo $objSite->homePage();

//ou

//Exemplo - 2
$arrInicializ ["userType"]= $_SESSION["userType"];
$objSite = new minhaClasse(arrInicializ);
echo $objSite->homePage();
```

No exemplo 1 não seria necessário inicializar a variável com o valor da sessão pois já é feito no construtor (default). Isso economizaria muitas linhas de código toda vez o objeto fosse usado.

No segundo exemplo teríamos que inicializar a varável a cada vez que o objeto fosse instanciado. Teríamos mais linha de código, porém não estarímaos usando a sessão dentro da classe.

O que conduz a um questionamento: usar sessão dentro de classes é uma boa prática ou não?

**Se sim**, poderíamos inclusive economizar variáveis dentro da classe (dentro dos métodos) pois poderíamos acessar o valor direto da $_SESSION. E com isso o código ficaria com menos linhas. Mas não sei se seria uma boa prática.

**Se não**, teríamos que iniciar as variáveis de classe com os valores das variáveis de sessão (a cada instancialização) e depois usar as variáveis dentro da classe (como diz a teoria - a boa prática), mas isso iria criar linhas "desnecessárias?" no código.

O que acham?

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso, eu compartilho com a mesma ideia que aprendi quando começei a aprender `Python`: *Explícito é melhor do que Implícito*

Por quê?

Quando passo dos dados com os quais vou trabalhar dentro de uma classe, fica mais fácil saber o que vai ser usado. Quando implicitamente você usa a `$_SESSION` dentro da classe, você pode estar limitando a sua utilização em vários fatores.

Quero dizer o seguinte: Se precisar fazer alguma alteração nos dados utilizados, você teria que "fuçar" o código fonte da sua classe. E não acredito que seja legal, pois talvez terá que mudar todos os pontos onde você está instanciando essa classe.

Como disse, prefiro "explícito do que "implícito". Então faria dessa forma:

```
class MinhaClasse
{
         protected $dadosSessao = [];

         public function __construct(array $dadosSessao, $outro = null)
         {
               $this->setDadosSessao($dadosSessao);
         }

         public function setDadosSessao($dadosSessao)
         {
             $this->dadosSessao = $dadosSessao;
         }


}
```

A forma de utilizar seria assim:

```
 $minha_classe = new MinhaClasse($_SESSION, OUTRO_VALOR);
```

Uma opção interessante que você pode fazer nesse caso é criar um método estático, que servirá para a criação da instância da sua classe baseada na `$_SESSION`. Esse método vai funcionar como uma fábrica.

```
class Session {

     // Pode receber os dados indepedente do mecanismo do PHP ou não

     public function __construct(array $data)

     {
          $this->data = $data;
     }

     public static function createFromGlobalSession()
     {
          return new static($_SESSION);
     }
}

$session = Session::createFromGlobalSession();
```